# Best practices for Swagger UI in production

Tags: go, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm working on a REST API with a Swagger UI. When it comes time to expose the API, should I expose the Swagger UI as well? If so, how would I package it into my application. Currently, I have the UI downloaded from the GitHub and am storing it in a folder alongside my project.

I'm using Go (with the Echo framework) to write the API.

Comment: Why you want to expose swagger UI publicly ? I normally use swag for developers and not use it in production.

Comment: Apologies, by publicly, I meant to other developers at the company. Just so they understand what endpoints are available for use.

Comment: I don't store doc in github, when needed you can use the command to generate again, and for developing you can do that like `if appEnv != "PRODUCTION" { e.GET("/swagger/*", echoSwagger.WrapHandler)}`

Comment: Ah okay I see, that makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

There can be security Threads if swagger exposed to production and can be accessed publicly like :

- **Increased attack surface:** Swagger becomes an additional entry point that can be targeted by potential Denial-of-Service (DoS) attacks.
- **Information exposure:** Swagger exposes detailed documentation about your API endpoints, request/response structures, and data models.
- **Injection vulnerabilities:** The exposed information in Swagger, including data formats, input validation, and implementation details, can aid attackers in launching injection attacks. Ex-  SQL injection or cross-site scripting (XSS), can manipulate or compromise data and system.
- **Unauthorized access risks:** Improper configuration of Swagger can result in unauthorized access to sensitive API endpoints or functionality.

Answer (score 0):

We should not enable swagger in production due to security threats.
In.net core version 6.0 version, we can protect it with the below code in Program.cs.

```
if(!app.Environment.IsProduction())    
{        
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>        
        {    
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Service");    
            c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;  // Set Swagger UI at apps root    
        });
}
```

Comment: What kind of security threats are there when you use swagger in production?

Comment: Yeah, what security threads are you talking about?

Comment: Probably no direct threats per se, but unless there's a good reason to include it in production, why would you give would-be attackers a blueprint to your API?

Comment: You should exclude it at compile time, not runtime. If you don't need it, it should not be there.